# How to count kafka topic message?

Tags: apache-kafka

[kafka consumer[kafka-producer][1]```
[root@kafka1 kafka_2.13-2.7.0]# bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list  kafka1:9092 --topic new-cluster-test  --time -1 --offsets 1 | awk -F  ":" '{sum += $3} END {print sum}'
[2021-05-18 02:33:16,390] WARN [Consumer clientId=GetOffsetShell, groupId=null] Bootstrap broker kafka1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-05-18 02:33:16,794] WARN [Consumer clientId=GetOffsetShell, groupId=null] Bootstrap broker kafka1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-05-18 02:33:17,198] WARN [Consumer clientId=GetOffsetShell, groupId=null] Bootstrap broker kafka1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-05-18 02:33:17,546] WARN [Consumer clientId=GetOffsetShell, groupId=null] Bootstrap broker kafka1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-05-18 02:33:17,824] WARN [Consumer clientId=GetOffsetShell, groupId=null] Bootstrap broker kafka1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-05-18 02:33:18,227] WARN [Consumer clientId=GetOffsetShell, groupId=null] Bootstrap broker kafka1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
^C
[root@kafka1 kafka_2.13-2.7.0]# bin/kafka-topics.sh --version
2.7.0 (Commit:448719dc99a19793)
[root@kafka1 kafka_2.13-2.7.0]#

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s93dH.png
```

Comment: https://rmoff.net/2020/09/08/counting-the-number-of-messages-in-a-kafka-topic/

Comment: @RobinMoffatt tried but getting same output

[2021-05-18 02:33:17,546] WARN [Consumer clientId=GetOffsetShell, groupId=null] Bootstrap broker kafka1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: There's not enough information here. `kafka1:9092` is clearly the incorrect address. Is Kafka running? You're already on that host, so why not use localhost? Is port 9092 correct?? Robin's link was simply to answer the title of your question, not solve your network setup

Comment: @OneCricketeer Kafka is running properly and we're also able to create topics and producing and consuming the messages as well but no able to count the no or messages received at consumer side.

Comment: Can you please show they work by editing the question? If console producer with `--broker-list  kafka1:9092`or consumer with bootstrap-servers on that same machine work, then there's no reason the offset shell shouldn't. But like I said, you're already in the terminal of kafka1, so you should also try using localhost

Comment: [root@kafka2 kafka_2.13-2.7.0]# bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic new-cluster-test --from-beginning --bootstrap-server kafka2:9092 --consumer.config config/client.properties
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is /opt/Roamware/Packages/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/kdc/private/kafka-client.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is huaweiseq@HUAWEI.COM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
principal is huaweiseq@HUAWEI.COM
Will use keytab
Commit Succeeded

Answer (score 0):

```
I was using SASL_PLAINTEXT listeners protocol with krb5 and so it is not authenticating without config(client.properties) file on port 9092.

I have exported the JMX_PORT in kafka-server-start.sh and added dual listeners for kafka (SASL_PLAINTEXT and PLAINTEXT) on separate port(9094).
Restarted the Zookeeper and Kakfa, Now I'm able to get the count.

[root@kafka1 kafka_2.13-2.7.0]# bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list kafka1:9094 --topic new-cluster-test --time -1  | awk -F ":" '{sum += $3} END {print sum}'
114
[root@kafka1 kafka_2.13-2.7.0]# bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list kafka1:9094 --topic new-cluster-test --time -1  
new-cluster-test:0:13
new-cluster-test:1:19
new-cluster-test:2:28
new-cluster-test:3:15
new-cluster-test:4:14
new-cluster-test:5:25
```